# How to cast a new type for the specific columns in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, casting, list-comprehension

I want to change types of 2 date fields in my spark dataframe to 'timestamp' as now they are of 'string' type.

Can anyone explain is there a way to create a oneliner for that?

So, my dataframe is called simply 'data' and what I'm trying to do is this:

```
data = data.select(*(col(c.lower()).cast('timestamp') for c in data.columns if c.lower().like('%date%'))
```

And all other modifications led to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this DataFrame (df):

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|           str_date|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|08-04-2023 10:00:00|
+---+-------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- str_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Use `to_timestamp()` function to convert it from `StringType` to `Timestamp` type

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = df.select(
    *(to_timestamp(f"{column}", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:m:ss").alias(column) for column in df.columns if re.search("date", column))
)

df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Output

```
+-------------------+
|           str_date|
+-------------------+
|2023-04-08 10:00:00|
+-------------------+

root
 |-- str_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So it all happened to be increadibly easier that anyone could have thought about.

Here's the solution:

```
data.select([col(c).cast('timestamp') if 'date' in c.lower() else col(c) for c in data.columns])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).